# Tornado app in multiple nginx locations

Tags: nginx, proxy, location, config, tornado

I have 2 tornado applications and I am trying to use nginx as a proxy for them, but I need those applications to be served in the same address but different *locations* (Access **app1** with URL `http://myserver/app1`, and **app2** with URL `http://myserver/app2`).

My nginx configuration file `/etc/nginx/conf.d/myserver.conf`:

```
upstream app1 {
    server 127.0.0.1:8081;
    server 127.0.0.1:8082;
}

upstream app2 {
    server 127.0.0.1:9081;
    server 127.0.0.1:9082;
}

server {
    listen 80;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/myserver.access.log;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/myserver.error.log;

    location app1/static {
        root /path/to/app1/;
        if ($query_string) {
            expires max;
        }
    }

    location app2/static {
        root /path/to/app2/;
        if ($query_string) {
            expires max;
        }
    }

    location /app1/ {
        proxy_pass_header Server;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
        proxy_pass http://app1/;
    }

    location /app2/ {
        proxy_pass_header Server;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
        proxy_pass http://app2/;
    }
}
```

When I access, for instance, **app1** via tornado it works fine:

- Via tornado: `http://myserver:8081/` redirects to login `http://myserver:8081/auth/login`. **Good**.
- Via nginx: `http://myserver/app1` redirects to `http://myserver/auth/login` (it should redirect to `http://myserver/app1/auth/login`).

What is the correct nginx configuration to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is controlled by the `proxy_redirects` setting.  You've turned it off, so when the tornado server redirects to `/auth/login` that gets passed through as-is.  You need to either make the tornado server aware of its urls as seen by the outside world (i.e. include /app1/ in all the routes and redirects even internally) or turn on `proxy_redirects` to have nginx remap them.  I recommend the former, since `proxy_redirects` only works for redirects and you'll usually run into similar issues in other places (urls for static content, for submission, etc).

Comment: Indeed, using `proxy_redirect` in this situation create more troubles with form submission and static files. I was trying to avoid change the routes in Tornado, but it is the best solution as you pointed out. Thanks.